# Get data from tinymce

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

Hi in a wizard on a confirmation tab i try to get the content from the tinymce editor. But it doesn't work. With normal textareas it works without any problems.

Example normal Textarea:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">MyValue<span class="required">*</span></label>
<div class="controls">
<textarea class="span12 m-wrap" style="max-width:100%;" name="MyValue" rows="7"></textarea>
</div></div>
```

Code to show text from textarea on the confirmation page:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">MyValue</label>
<div class="controls">
<span class="text display-value" data-display="MyValue"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
        var displayConfirm = function() {
            $('.display-value', form).each(function(){
                var input = $('[name="'+$(this).attr("data-display")+'"]', form);
                if (input.is(":text") || input.is("textarea")) {
                    $(this).html(input.val());
                } else if (input.is("select")) {
                    $(this).html(input.find('option:selected').text());
                } else if (input.is(":radio") && input.is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).html(input.attr("data-title"));
                } else if ($(this).attr("data-display") == 'htmlinhalt') {
                    $(this).html($('[name="htmlinhalt"]', form).val());
                } 
            });
        }
```

But why it doesn't work with a tinymce textarea? I think I must get the content directly from tinymce not from textarea, but how?

Comment: Have you tried `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` before starting any submission or validation?

Comment: No I still doesn't try it. For Info: The tinymce code is not in the self js file than my displayConfirm javascript code. @MahanGM if i write it above my javascript code. Nothing happens. Or where I must integrate it?

Comment: There is one thing that you should know, when you're editing with TinyMCE it's not going to use from the textarea that you've provided instead it's using its inner html frame tag to keep and show the data. You must do an update like saving the trigger to get data into that textarea.

Comment: @MahanGM so I can't show the conten't on the 3 tab from my wizard with javascript?

---- I also find var ed = tinymce.activeEditor; // get editor instance
ed.save(); //save editor content to textarea --- But how to integrate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
tinymce.get('your_textarea_id').getContent();
```

Comment: where i must integrate it?

Comment: in the texarea section of your code, just be sure to use the correct textare-ID

Comment: You realy mean in my textarea section or in the output?

Comment: Ok you mean here: else if ($(this).attr("data-display") == 'htmlinhalt') {tinyMCE.get('MyID').getContent();} -- still nothing

Comment: Oh soory I see it... I forget something :-) $(this).html(tinymce.get('htmlinhalt').getContent()); ok if I do that in the first I get the value. If I use it in else if ($(this).attr("data-display") == 'htmlinhalt') {... it doesn't work... any idea? Perhaps I have here also a mistake?

Comment: are you sure that you have a tinymce editor in the else case?

Comment: You are iterating through all elements in your form using $('.display-value', form) . Without knowledge of your full html and javascript code i can only guess, but it looks like there can only be an editor in the textare case. I do not know what kind of elements have which attributes in your form.

Comment: I think the false is in: else if (($(this).attr("data-display") == 'htmlinhalt')) {... ----- for the other elements I use else if (input.is(":radio") && input.is(":checked") for example.

Comment: then you need to find out what kind of elements that are

Comment: The display-value comes from: <span class="text display-value" data-display="htmlinhlt"></span>

Comment: ok, and this element does it refer to a tinymce editor instance?

Comment: For example in an other function I use: else if ($(this).attr("data-display") == 'card_expiry') {$(this).html($('[name="card_expiry_mm"]', form).val() + '/' + $('[name="card_expiry_yyyy"]', form).val());}

Comment: The name of editor input "htmlinhalt"
----------------------------------            
Input:
<textarea class="span12 m-wrap" name="htmlinhalt" id="htmlinhalt" rows="15"></textarea>
----------------------------------           
Output:              <span class="text display-value" data-display="htmlinhalt"></span>

Comment: Ok now it works :-) I changed it to:  else if (input.is("textarea") && $(this).attr("data-display") == 'htmlinhalt') {
                     $(this).html(tinymce.get('htmlinhalt').getContent());
                 } else if (input.is("textarea") && $(this).attr("data-display") == 'textinhalt') {
                     $(this).html(input.val());
                 }

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and the previous answer wouldn't work for me either. The problem for me was that my textarea had no id. After giving it an id I was able to get the content easily with the previous answer (albeit with capital 'MCE'):

```
tinyMCE.get('your_textarea_id').getContent();
```

So you want to add an extra line into your if statement. If you give the textarea the same id as its name then this should work:

```
   var displayConfirm = function() {
        $('.display-value', form).each(function(){
            var input = $('[name="'+$(this).attr("data-display")+'"]', form);
            if (input.is(":text")) {
                $(this).html(input.val());
            } else if (input.is("textarea")) {
                $(this).html(tinyMCE.get($(this).attr("data-display")).getContent());
            } else if (input.is("select")) {
                $(this).html(input.find('option:selected').text());
            } else if (input.is(":radio") && input.is(":checked")) {
                $(this).html(input.attr("data-title"));
            } else if ($(this).attr("data-display") == 'htmlinhalt') {
                $(this).html($('[name="htmlinhalt"]', form).val());
            } 
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the raw contents (with html tags), or only the text (html striped). The default format returned with function getContent() is the raw.

```
<textarea id="MyValue" name="MyValue"></textarea>
<div>
    <a href="javascript:alert(tinymce.EditorManager.get('MyValue').getContent({format : 'raw'}));">[getRawContents]</a>
    <a href="javascript:alert(tinymce.EditorManager.get('MyValue').getContent({format : 'text'}));">[getTextContents]</a>
    <a href="javascript:alert(tinymce.EditorManager.get('MyValue').getContent());">[getContents]</a>
</div>
```

I use MyValue since you use in the your question. Change for your_textarea_id if needed.

More information for tinyMCE 3.x in [API 3](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent)
More information for tinyMCE 4.x in [API 4](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3aproperty.tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor)